# Show $x^2 \equiv 94 \pmod{195}$ if and only if $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, $x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ , $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{13}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

> Show $x^2 \equiv 94\pmod {195}$ if and only if $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, $x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ , $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod {13}$

I've already proved $x^2 \equiv 94 \pmod {195}$ implies $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, $x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ , $x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod {13}$ by noting $3,5,13$ divides $195$ and then using congruence classes implying $[94]_3 = 1, [94]_4 = 4, [94]_{13} = 3$. This is right ?

However I have trouble proving the other implication.

I know

$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ iff. $x = 1,2 \pmod 3$,

$x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$ iff. $x \equiv 2,3 \pmod 5$ ,

$x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod {13}$ iff. $x \equiv 4,9 \pmod {13}$

Comment: Your approach is right (see chinese remainder theorem). The quadratic equations $x^2$=a (mod p) have at most 2 solutions, when p is prime.

Comment: It should be $x^2 \equiv 94 \pmod {195}$

Comment: Forget about square set $x^2=y$ use CRT as $3,5,13$ are pairwise primes

Comment: No, $\pmod {195}$.

Comment: Why does $x^2 \equiv a \pmod p$ have at most $2$ solutions for $p$ prime ?

Comment: Because the ring Z[p] is a field when p is prime and in a field, a polynomial with degree 2 has at most 2 roots.

Comment: @lab Nicolas used the CRT.

Comment: But solving using CRT produces a solution to the three equations. But why is this a solution to the larger congruence ?

Comment: Doh, I should have noted that all the smaller congruences could be turned into $x^2 \equiv 94 \pmod p$ where $p = 3,5,13$. Thanks.

Comment: "If x^2=a (mod p), then also x^2=a (mod n) holds, if p divides n". Why is this true ? Shouldn't it be opposite ?

Comment: Forget this statement, you are, of course, right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that each congruence:

$$x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \iff x^2 \equiv 94 \pmod 3$$

$$x^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5 \iff x^2 \equiv 94 \pmod 5$$

$$x^2 \equiv 3 \pmod {13} \iff x^2 \equiv 94 \pmod {13}$$

since $$[1]_3 = [94]_3, [4]_5 = [94]_5, [3]_{13} = [94]_{13}$$

From here we can reduce to the linear congruence's shown in question, and the result easily follows using the CRT.

A solution to the linear congruence's is $x = 113$. Now $a \mid c \land b \mid c \land \gcd(a,b) = 1 \Rightarrow ab \mid c$. Thus we have $x^2 \equiv 94\pmod {3\cdot5\cdot13=195}$